# How should I make a button higher without effecting other elements?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a navigation bar at the top of my website.

HTML:

```html
<text align="center">
<div class="home-nav">
<a href="#whats-new"><button class="nav-btn">What's New</button></a>
<a href=""><button class="nav-btn">Community</button></a>
<button class="play-btn">Coming Soon</button>
<button class="nav-btn">Profile</button>
<a href=""><button class="nav-btn">Information</button></a>
</text>
```

CSS:

```css
.home-nav {
    width:1240px;
 height:49px;
 background-color:#F1B84E;
 border:5px solid #FFDE84;
 border-style:outset;
} 

.nav-btn {
 width:auto;
 height:49px;
 background-color:#F1B84E;
 border:none;
 font-family:showcard gothic;
 color:white;
 -webkit-text-stroke:1.25px #000000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:#FFFFFF;
 font-size:20px;
}

.play-btn {
    width:auto;
    height:69px;
 background-color:#79E119;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
 border:5px solid #FFFFFF;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:showcard gothic;
 color:white;
}
```

I want the play button to be bigger than the normal buttons. But when I make the height higher than the normal buttons and look at it, it makes the normal buttons change position. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have bring some small changes to your CSS styling just try these and let me know its working as you wanted or not.

```
body{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.home-nav {
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-color:#F1B84E;
    border:5px solid #FFDE84;
    border-style:outset;
 }  

.nav-btn {
    width:auto;
    height:49px;
    background-color:#F1B84E;
    border:none;
    font-family:showcard gothic;
    color:white;
    -webkit-text-stroke:1.25px #000000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:20px;
}

.play-btn {
    width:auto;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#79E119;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border:5px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:showcard gothic;
    color:white;
   }
```